# Changing embedded google videos src

Tags: javascript, video

I'm trying to recreate the functionality on Google Video where you can access certain parts of a video by putting `#1h1m1m` in the URL.

So I have an embedded Google Video and links to the right that I want to link to at certain times in that video.

I can do this with a page refresh but I'm trying to do it via javascript so I don't have to.

I can't seem to get the src of an embed element via javascript for whatever reason.

I don't have a link because I haven't figured it out yet. I just want to skip to a different section of a Google Video without reloading the page.

Comment: it would perhaps help if you showed us the page of what you try to do, preferably browseable.

Comment: At least you could provide a link to a page where this url based video seeking is in use. You must have one since you know it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the google video you are embedding is a YouTube video, there are documented APIs for causing the player to seek to a specified time (expressed in secondes).

See: [YouTube Javascript API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html)